# Use a template inside a template that have the same type

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

im doing a project for school and i have a problem with templates : i'd like to use a template with the same type as my actual template in its constructor but i come with this error : declaration incompatible with "my construcor".

Here's the code :

```cpp
template <typename Type> class CMatrixIterator : public CIterator
{
      CMatrixIterator(CMatrix<Type>& MATmatrice);
}

template <typename Type>
inline CMatrixIterator<Type>::CMatrixIterator(CMatrix<Type>& MATmatrice) : iIndex(0), MATmatrice(MATmatrice)
{
}
```

and the full error :

```
declaration incompatible with "CMatrixIterator<Type>::CMatrixIterator(<error-type> & MATmatrice)
```

I dont understand why i get this error does anyone have an idea ?
Thanx.

full code :

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "CIterator.h"
#include "CMatrix.h"

template <typename Type> class CMatrixIterator : public CIterator
{
    private:
        int iIndex;
        CMatrix<Type>& MATmatrice;

    public:
        CMatrixIterator(CMatrix<Type>& MATmatrice);
        ~CMatrixIterator();

        virtual Type ITEfirst();
        virtual bool ITEisDone();
        virtual void ITEnext();
        virtual Type ITEcurrentItem();
};



template <typename Type>
inline CMatrixIterator<Type>::CMatrixIterator(CMatrix<Type>& MATmatrice) : iIndex(0), MATmatrice(MATmatrice)
{
}

template<typename Type>
inline CMatrixIterator<Type>::~CMatrixIterator()
{
}

template<typename Type>
inline Type CMatrixIterator<Type>::ITEfirst()
{
    return MATmatrice.getValues(0, 0);
}

template<typename Type>
inline bool CMatrixIterator<Type>::ITEisDone()
{
    return MATmatrice.MATrows * MATmatrice.MATcols() > index ? true : false;
}

template<typename Type>
inline void CMatrixIterator<Type>::ITEnext()
{
    iIndex++;
}

template<typename Type>
inline Type CMatrixIterator<Type>::ITEcurrentItem()
{
    return MATmatrice.MATgetValues(iIndex % MATmatrice.MATcols, iIndex / MATmatrice.MATcols);
}
```

Comment: If `CMatrix<T>` declared by the time you reach the place you define your constructor? This might be a cyclical header dependency problem.

Comment: i have 
`#pragma once
#include "CIterator.h"
#include "CMatrix.h"`
At top of my file

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/oE99ZvcRkjJQQzqY, but this is with gcc.  Next time, please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Cannot reproduce with MSVC either, see: https://rextester.com/QKWMW15635

Comment: Thanks for your help, i edited my first post. It seems to work on your links, maybe its a problem with visual studio ?

Comment: @LelaidierLucas Does either `CIterator.h` or `CMatrix.h` include the file containing the code you've shown?

Comment: Hum yeah it solve the problem ! Thanks but why this error message ?

Comment: @LelaidierLucas I'm not sure what you actually did, so it's hard to say exactly. You would have to share exactly which file includes which file for a precise explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CMatrix declared by the time you reach the place you define your constructor? This might be a cyclical header dependency problem.

Does either CIterator.h or CMatrix.h include the file containing the code you've shown?

François Andrieux.